# Nothing is written to log in log_directory() for a PostgreSQL cluster

Tags: postgresql

Running PostgresSQL 11.4 on Windows 10

I made a DB cluster in  `C:\Users\WindowsUser\AppData\Roaming\postgresql\Db_1`

I registered that cluster to start on as a windows service on startup:

```
pg_ctl register -D C:\Users\WindowsUser\AppData\Roaming\postgresql\Db_1 -N PostgreSQLdb1 -U WindowsUser -P WindowsPassword  -S a
```

And the [Where to log](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-DIRECTORY) In `C:\Users\WindowsUser\AppData\Roaming\postgresql\Db_1\postgresql.conf` I changed the log parameter to a absolute location.:

```
# - Where to Log -
log_destination = 'stderr'      # Valid values are combinations of
          # stderr, csvlog, syslog, and eventlog,
          # depending on platform.  csvlog
          # requires logging_collector to be on.
# This is used when logging to stderr:
logging_collector = on      # Enable capturing of stderr and csvlog
          # into log files. Required to be on for
          # csvlogs.
          # (change requires restart)
# These are only used if logging_collector is on:
log_directory = 'C:\Users\WindowsUser\AppData\Roaming\postgresql\Db_1\log' 
                      # directory where log files are written,
          # can be absolute or relative to PGDATA
log_filename = 'postgresql-%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S.log' # log file name pattern, 
          # can include strftime() escapes
```

However, the cluster database does not write anything to log. The main PG database is located in a totally different directory, and that database does write to its log file.

Both databases works just fine, except the log part.

I have have even restarted my PC, but it still does not write to log.

Comment: Try to start the database from the command line using `pg_ctl start -D :\Users\WindowsUser\AppData\Roaming\postgresql\Db_:\Users\WindowsUser\AppData\Roaming\postgresql\Db_1` (after stopping the service). That should show you potential problems. Perhaps the permissions are wrong?

Comment: That gave me an error: `pg_ctl: directory ":/Users/WindowsUser/AppData/Roaming/postgresql/Db_:/Users/WindowsUser/AppData/Roaming/postgresql/Db_1" does not exist` .

However this does work if a specify a specific log file: `pg_ctl start -D "C:\Users\WindowsUser\AppData\Ro" -l "C:\Users\WindowsUser\AppData\Ro\log\postgresql-2019-10-14.log"`

Comment: Well, **does** the directory exist? If it does, are the privileges setup correctly, so that the service account that runs Postgres (`WindowsUser`) can write into that directory? Unrelated, but I prefer a relative directory: `log_directory = 'log'`

Comment: Sorry, I meant `pg_ctl start -D C:\Users\WindowsUser\AppData\Roaming\postgresql\Db_1`. Hmm. Your question has a `Roaming` in there, your comment doesn't. What's going on there? Try to change `log_directory` in `postgresql.conf`. If that causes a log file to be written, then it must be some kind of permission problem.

Comment: Ok, so my previous comment missed a few characters. I got it working when I entered a specified log file with the manual  `pg_ctl start -D "C:\Users\WindowsUser\AppData\Roaming\postgresql\Db_1"   -l "C:\Users\WindowsUser\AppData\Roaming\postgresql\Db_1\log\db1_logfile.log"`. I also tried with `log_directory = 'log'`, but when nothing happened, I tried with the absolute dir-path instead. The user `WindowsUser` is an admin, so it should have write privileges. However, I added my "answer" below with the event-log alternative.

Comment: Just because a Windows user is "admin", doesn't mean that account can read and write everywhere automatically. It's just possible with that account to change the privileges. If the `log` directory was not created by that admin user, then unless the privileges or the owner is changed manually, the account can not write into that directory

Comment: I just checked the privileges for both the files and the folders for `WindowsUser`, and it did both have read and write privileges. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I did not get the Log files to work. But instead I got the Windows event log to work.

In `postgresql.conf` I set these line uncommented with those options:

```
log_destination = 'eventlog'        # Valid values are combinations of
                    # stderr, csvlog, syslog, and eventlog,
                    # depending on platform.  csvlog
                    # requires logging_collector to be on.

# This is only relevant when logging to eventlog (win32):
# (change requires restart)
event_source = 'PostgreSQL'

log_statement = 'all'    # none, ddl, mod, all
```

- To register The Event log to Windows, [I followed these instructions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/event-log-registration.html)
- I entered this command: `REGSVR32 "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\lib\pgevent.dll"` and a pop-up dialog confirmed that the `pgevent.dll` was registerd to `REGSVR32`
- Then I opened Windows Event Viewer
- On the right hand side, I chose Create custom view and got this pop-up dialog. I just filtered by the event source.

[image: Pop-up dialog to configure the custom view]

Then i get a neat list of events.

[image: Windows Event Viewer]